# Issues Extending a jobdsl command to a groovy class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am having an issue extending a utilizing a jobdsl command from a groovy script.

I have created a helper class and i am passing "this". It works for jobdsl commands that do not require closures. But fails with invalid property for job dsl command that accepts closures. Example is the freestylejob("inputstring"){}

Helper Code

```
static freeJob(def fJ, def dslFactory){
    def txt = dslFactory.freeStyleJob(fJ){

    }
}
```

Caller Code

```
def testjob = DS.freeJob("inputstring", this)
```

I expect no errors. Instead i am getting the error below from jenkins.

> ERROR: (filename.groovy, line 119) No signature of method: .filename.freeStyleJob() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, classname$_classname_closure3) values: [inputstring, classname$_project_closure3@5c7bc682]

Comment: maybe you just need to use shared library?  could you show the result of `dslFactory.getClass()` and `dslFactory.getClass().getSuperclass()`

Comment: for dslFactory.getClass() it is class java.lang.Class  and for dslFactory.getClass().getSuperclass() it is class java.lang.Object

Comment: Thank you. Your question was able to point me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was calling the method from a class deep. Issue resolved.